# How to deduce the right target for a GCC cross-build?

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

I have a 32 bit x86 machine where Debian is up and running with this properties

- `uname -r` is `3.2.0-4-486` and
- `uname -m` is `i586`

in this situation i have to pick the right `HOST` and `TARGET` prefix so I will be able to cross compile gcc on another machine for this Debian installation.

I should pick `i486` or `i586` ? I already tried `i686` but apparently it doesn't work at all ( gcc compiles and runs, it's the gcc/g++ compiler that doesn't find the headers on the machine using the `i686` prefix ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't need to cross compile. You can simply use `-march` to indicate the `cpu-type`. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html for the complete list. In your case, `-march=i586` should work.

Comment: thanks, but my question is about deducing the right prefix for the build

Comment: I probably haven't understood your question then. Could you describe how you use the prefix exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You should not deduce, you must know and choose the one you need, if you needed compatibility with an old 486 or the best performance with your 686.

The missing headers are just a different issue.

Comment: and how to solve the "missing headers" problem ?

Comment: the `-march` didn't solved? edit your question and post the log with the missing headers

Comment: That's a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/11739573/2498790